# OR-Tools CVRP with Multiple Trips

Tags: traveling-salesman, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I'm trying to use OR-Tools' Routing Solver to solve a Multi Trip Capacitated VRP. What I need is

- one depot, route starts and ends here.
- one unloading location (different from the depot)
- set time window and demand for each node

So the vehicles should pick up the goods from each node until the capacity is filled. Then go to "unloading location", unload all their weight and keep collecting the demand from nodes until a time limit is reached or all the goods are collected. Then return back to the depot.

[CVRP Reload Example](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrp_reload.py) seems very close but in my case, at the end of the route vehicles should visit the unloading location before the depot. In other words a vehicle can not go to the depot (starting, ending location) with load.

Example:

```
0: Depot
1: Unloading Location
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7: Nodes to pick up demand


0 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 1 (unload) > 5 > 6 > 7 > 1 (unload) > 0
0 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 1 (unload) > 5 > 6 > 7 > 0 This is the result cvrp_reload returns.
```

I'm fairly new to or-tools, and trying to figure it out. Can you help me if you have any ideas?

- I'm using Python and or-tools v8.2
- This is a cross-post from [github](https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/2442).

I think, it's possible to implement a preceding constraint before the last point (unload before depot) by using a count_dimension but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/2442#discussioncomment-493097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add

```py
    # Vehicles must be empty upon arrival
    capacity_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie("Capacity")
    for v in range(manager.GetNumberOfVehicles()):
        print(f"vehicle {v}")
        end = routing.End(v)
        #routing.solver().Add(capacity_dimension.CumulVar(end) == 0) # see comment below
        capacity_dimension.SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound(end, 0, 100_000)
```

possible output:

```sh
./2442_unload.py
...
I0417 23:53:02.181640 17437 search.cc:260] Solution #317 (372696, objective maximum = 4838552, time = 2969 ms, branches = 3223, failures = 940, depth = 33, MakeInactiveOperator, neighbors = 265820, filtered neighbors = 317, accepted neighbors = 317, memory used = 14.93 MB, limit = 99%)
I0417 23:53:20.290527 17437 search.cc:260] Solution #318 (469816, objective minimum = 372696, objective maximum = 4838552, time = 2987 ms, branches = 3239, failures = 945, depth = 33, MakeInactiveOperator, neighbors = 267395, filtered neighbors = 318, accepted neighbors = 318, memory used = 14.93 MB, limit = 99%)
I0417 23:53:21.045410 17437 search.cc:260] Solution #319 (469816, objective minimum = 372696, objective maximum = 4838552, time = 2988 ms, branches = 3247, failures = 947, depth = 33, MakeActiveOperator, neighbors = 267415, filtered neighbors = 319, accepted neighbors = 319, memory used = 14.93 MB, limit = 99%)
I0417 23:53:22.304931 17437 search.cc:260] Solution #320 (372696, objective maximum = 4838552, time = 2989 ms, branches = 3253, failures = 949, depth = 33, MakeActiveOperator, neighbors = 267464, filtered neighbors = 320, accepted neighbors = 320, memory used = 14.93 MB, limit = 99%)
I0417 23:53:30.987548 17437 search.cc:260] Finished search tree (time = 2998 ms, branches = 3259, failures = 982, neighbors = 268318, filtered neighbors = 320, accepted neigbors = 320, memory used = 14.93 MB)
I0417 23:53:31.046630 17437 search.cc:260] End search (time = 2998 ms, branches = 3259, failures = 982, memory used = 14.93 MB, speed = 1087 branches/s)
Objective: 372696
dropped orders: [25]
dropped reload stations: [3, 5]
Route for vehicle 0:
 0 Load(0) Time(0,0) -> 20 Load(0) Time(75,506) -> 12 Load(3) Time(94,525) -> 14 Load(6) Time(119,550) -> 13 Load(10) Time(140,700) -> 8 Load(13) Time(159,1000) -> 0 Load(0) Time(237,1500)
Distance of the route: 2624m
Load of the route: 0
Time of the route: 237min

Route for vehicle 1:
 1 Load(0) Time(0,0) -> 19 Load(0) Time(2,182) -> 24 Load(3) Time(20,200) -> 26 Load(7) Time(42,400) -> 4 Load(15) Time(89,770) -> 7 Load(15) Time(92,773) -> 11 Load(0) Time(169,850) -> 17 Load(3) Time(188,959) -> 10 Load(11) Time(229,1000) -> 1 Load(0) Time(307,1500)
Distance of the route: 2648m
Load of the route: 0
Time of the route: 307min

Route for vehicle 2:
 2 Load(0) Time(0,0) -> 23 Load(0) Time(15,63) -> 22 Load(4) Time(37,85) -> 21 Load(7) Time(85,101) -> 9 Load(10) Time(104,120) -> 18 Load(0) Time(184,200) -> 16 Load(8) Time(226,600) -> 15 Load(12) Time(248,800) -> 6 Load(15) Time(268,1000) -> 2 Load(0) Time(346,1500)
Distance of the route: 2624m
Load of the route: 0
Time of the route: 346min

Total Distance of all routes: 7896m
Total Load of all routes: 0
Total Time of all routes: 890min
```

note: I use the Soft constraint since otherwise the solver prefer to drop all nodes and never manage to escape form this solution search space point.